# usb microphone not working

Tags: usb, sound, microphone

I have a 6.35mm mono microphone and I bought a converter for 3.5mm jack and a usb sound card.

Now I connected microphone with both of them to my ubuntu 16.10 laptop. Ubuntu recognized it but it doesn't have any sound. I turned on the microphone and used `pavucontrol` and `sudo alsa force-reload` but it didn't work.

When I touch the jack, it makes sound in sound setting panel. But when I speak it doesn't grab my voice.

[image: sound setting panel]

Comment: Did you find a solution?